# Keep Specific Columns From Repeating in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

There is a report that I pull from our ERP system that lists order detail information. It will list the order number, customer code, customer name, order date, order status, order total, product code, product name, and qty ordered, unit price and extended price. If an order has multiple lines, then the header information is listed multiple times.

This is what the raw data looks like.
[image: OrderReportUnformatted]

I am trying to find a way in excel to keep the header lines from repeating for each of the line detail lines.

I would prefer the data to look like this when I am done. Basically each of the lines repeating under their respective header rows.
[image: OrderReportFormatted1]

<s>Another acceptable format could be below. I think this may be more simple.</s> I was able to do this with a Pivot table.
[image]

I am not sure if this would require VBA or not. I have tried highlighting the rows and using remove duplicates, but that moves all of the lines together. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could be done in VBa, may even be possible using pivot tables. Did you try either yet?

Comment: @Dave OK I was finally able to accomplish #2 with a Pivot. I would still like to see if there is a solution to Example #1. I have not tried VBA for Example #1 yet. I was really hoping to find a way built into Excel first as my VBA is a little rusty.

Comment: Why? I mean, well done for doing it in a pivot table, I suspected that was the most realistic approach - what you want, (the first image) is a big task, IMO outside of what the site is for, you'd need to learn the VBa yourself, or at least attempt more first (or outsource it)!

Comment: @dave One of the main reasons why Example #1 could be more helpful is that there are actually quite a few more columns in the report that I listed here (for example sake) so the report becomes rather large. I always like to believe that there are ways to handle these situations built into Excel, and since I was not finding it, why not come ask the community here who surely knows the capabilities of Excel better than I. :-) Thanks for the info, I will go ahead and try this in VBA and post what I find!

Comment: What you want would actually be pretty easy in VBA so long as it's OK to create a second worksheet with the formatted data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I know this is frowned upon, but the problem sounded interesting so I just wrote the VBA**

---

Try the code below. I set the constants to work for the example you gave but you might want to change them for your actual application.

```
Function CompressReport()

    'Settings for which columns are the header and details
    Const fHC As Long = 1   'First header column number
    Const lHC As Long = 6   'Last header column number
    Const fDC As Long = 7   'First detail column number
    Const lDC As Long = 11  'Last detail column number

    'Declarations
    Dim rStart&, rStop&, rNew As Long
    Dim r&, c As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim s1$, s2 As String

    'Set the source worksheet to be compressed
    '(Here are a few methods to do this. Pick one.)
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Add a new worksheet for our results
    Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=ws)

    With ws
        'Copy the first row of headers
        .Range(.Cells(1, fHC), .Cells(1, lHC)).Copy wsNew.Cells(1, 1)
        rNew = 2

        'Loop through all the rows
        For rStart = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

            'Copy the header information
            .Range(.Cells(rStart, fHC), .Cells(rStart, lHC)).Copy wsNew.Cells(rNew, 1)

            'Add a thick border (This wasn't in the OP but I recommend it)
            With wsNew.Range(wsNew.Cells(rNew, 1), wsNew.Cells(rNew, lHC - fHC + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous   'You could also try xlDouble
                .Weight = xlThick
            End With

            'Collect the header information into a single unique ID
            s1 = ""
            For c = fHC To lHC
                s1 = s1 & "|" & .Cells(rStart, c).Value
            Next

            'Find the next row with different information
            For rStop = rStart + 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
                s2 = ""
                For c = fHC To lHC
                    s2 = s2 & "|" & .Cells(rStop, c).Value
                Next
                If s2 <> s1 Then Exit For
            Next
            rStop = rStop - 1

            'Copy the detail headers and information
            .Range(.Cells(1, fDC), .Cells(1, lDC)).Copy wsNew.Cells(rNew + 1, 2)
            .Range(.Cells(rStart, fDC), .Cells(rStop, lDC)).Copy wsNew.Cells(rNew + 2, 2)

            'Increase the row we're pasting in the new worksheet
            ' +1 for header data, +1 for detail headers, +n for detail information
            rNew = rNew + 1 + 1 + (rStop - rStart + 1)

            'Increase the row we're copying in the source worksheet
            rStart = rStop  'The FOR loop will iterate it +1

        Next

    End With

    'Formatting (feel free to add to this part)
    With wsNew
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    'Cleanup
    Set wsNew = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tiny trick to accomplish your goal.  It can be applied to cells in any column.  Say we start with:

[image]

And we want to avoid seeing all the extra *Mike*'s, etc.We click on cell **A2** and apply Conditional Formatting so that if the value of the cell is the same as the cell above it, make the color of the font the same as the color of the cell background:

[image]

We then copy cell **A2** and PasteSpecialFormats down the column.  This "hides" the repeating values:

[image]

The actual data is left intact, only the display is changed !

Comment: This is definitely another (out of the box) way to handle. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I put

[image: CSV data in the markdown; click “Edit” to access]

into Sheet1, and I was able to get Sheet2 to look like this:

[image]

It uses two helper columns,
which, of course, you can move as far to the right as you want (or need) to,
and which you can hide.

- Set `A1` (on Sheet2) to `=Sheet1!A1` and drag to the right
  to cover the columns that would otherwise be duplicated across multiple lines. 
  In your example, this would be Column `F`. 
  (In my example, it is Column `C`.)
- Set `Y2` to `2` and `Z2` to `1`. 
  The value in Column `Y` says what Sheet1 row *this* row is pulling data from. 
  Column `Z` is `1` if this is a header row
  (pulling data from the left-hand columns of Sheet1; i.e., key fields),
  `2` if this is a subheading row, `3` if this is a sub-data row
  (pulling data from the right-hand columns of Sheet1),
  and `0` if this is a blank row (below the last data row).
- Set `A2` to `=IF($Z2=1, INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, $Y2), "")`.  If applicable,
  drag to the right to cover the columns that are used only for key data. 
  In your example, this is not applicable,
  because you have non-key data starting in Column `B`. 
  (In my example, it is through Column `B`.) 
  This implements the definitions of the helper columns:
  if `Z` is `1`, pull the key data from Sheet1, otherwise, blank.
- In my example, I set `C2` to

  ```
  =CHOOSE($Z2+1, "", INDEX(Sheet1!C:C, $Y2), Sheet1!D$1, INDEX(Sheet1!D:D, $Y2))
  ```

  In your example, you should set `B2` to

  ```
  =CHOOSE($Z2+1, "", INDEX(Sheet1!B:B, $Y2), Sheet1!G$1, INDEX(Sheet1!G:G, $Y2))
  ```

  reflecting the two Sheet1 columns that Sheet2 Column `B` might be pulling from:

  - Column `B` (“Cust Code”), or
  - Column `G` (“Product Code”)

  Again, this just does what the helper columns tell it to do. 
  We add `1` to the `Z` value to map `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`
  to `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. 
  `CHOOSE` uses the first argument to index into the following arguments, so

  - If `Z` is `0`, blank,
  - If `Z` is `1`, get the key data,
  - If `Z` is `2`, get the heading from Sheet1 Row `1`, and
  - If `Z` is `3`, get the non-key data.
- Set `Y3` to `=IF($Z2<3, $Y2, $Y2+1)` and `Z3` to

  ```
  =IF($Z2=0, 0, IF($Z2<3, $Z2+1, IF(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,$Y2+1)="", 0,
                      IF(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,$Y2)=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,$Y2+1), 3, 1))))
  ```

  (all on one line). 
  These say, if the `Z` value on the previous row is `1` or `2` (or `0`),
  set this `Y` value to the same as the previous row’s value. 
  This is because every row in your database table
  (every set of unique value in Columns `A`-`F` on Sheet1)
  results in at least three rows on Sheet2. 
  Otherwise, increment the `Y` value, to address the next row on Sheet1.

  If the previous `Z` value is `0`, we’re done, and fill in with zeros. 
  If the previous `Z` value is `1` or `2`, step up to the next value. 
  Otherwise, look at the Sheet1 key data. 
  If it’s blank, assume that we’re at the end of the data and set `Z` to `0`. 
  If it’s the same as the previous row, use `3` to continue what we’re doing. 
  Otherwise, we’re into a new set of unique values,
  so restart the cycle with a `1`.
- Drag down far enough to get all your data.

If your unique values are not individually unique
(e.g., if you might have `A4`=`A5` but `B4`≠`B5`),
expand the tests in Column `Z`
to test as many columns as you need to (combining them with `AND(…)`).

Obviously I used conditional formatting, with a formula of `=$Z2=2`,
to format the subheadings appropriately.